# Как мне правильно создать раздел для диска?

Tags: linux, parrot, parrot-os

У нас практическая работа в универе учимся работать с утилитой Scalpel в Parrot OS, такая проблема после установки ОС мы должны создать новый раздел диска, примонтировав его мы должны восстановить с него какие либо файлы, примерно вот такая работа:https:[сама практическая работа](https://hackmd.io/@spvrk/Sk6ZlzSvc), я сломал систему 1 раз неправильно создав раздел через fdisk, пытаюсь через Gparted, не получается, помогите пожалуйста.[image: вот здесь мы видим то что я не могу создать раздел для этого диска]

Comment: Ты из под системы, на которой работаешь - хочешь изменить раздел, на котором эта система усталновлена?

Comment: уже исправил спасибо

Comment: Ну а как исправил-то?